# url rewrite with blog url included

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to configure my website with blog for url rewriting. to make it seo friendly i have placed url rewrite, where it count www.amadcrew.com and http://www.amadcrew.com saperate urls. following is the code which made it working perfectly.

```
# Redirect to www location
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^amadcrew.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.amadcrew.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

but some how i am unable to run my blog which url is .amadcrew/madcrew_blog. before it was working perfectly and now there is a white page i see.

kindly help me for url rewriting for seo friendly.

thanks

Comment: Are you sure? `RewriteEngine Off` disables the rewrite engine completely and all rewrite rules are commented out.

Comment: my mistake... actually was trying all the possibilities... i

Comment: i have made the changes.

Comment: A white page usually means you have a `fatal error` in your PHP code. I don't believe that's an rewrite problem. Check your apache error log for your site.

Comment: yesterday it was perfectly alright as i was adding rss blog plugin. today even it run well. but when i added htaccess it start behaving such way. now i tried to remove the htaccess but result is same. something remain enable and its making problem.. please guid

Comment: As said, check your Apache error log. Also turn error reporting in PHP on to identify the issue. I think some statement in the `.htaccess` throws a 500.